# Bessel function and exponentials

Tags: improper-integrals, bessel-functions

I really need this integral to be solved:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\quad x^{-1}\,J_1(a\sqrt{x^2+1})\,J_1(b\sqrt{x^2+1})\,\exp(-cx^2)\,\,dx$$

Please, help!!!!!

Comment: I've looked in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik and cannot find such an integral. I will check my copy of the NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions tomorrow to see if I can find it, but I don't have much hope. Integrals involving Bessel functions can be really sparce because the integrals are very complicated. Try doing a change of variable to get it in a more manageable form first. Perhaps try using a hyperbolic function in a $u$ substitution, i.e. let $x = \sinh(x)$ (or $\cosh(x)$) and see if that simplifies anything.

Comment: You should definitely get your hands on a copy of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik because it has very complicated integrals which can be very difficult to figure out by hand. Integrals such as this one can be simplified in such a manner.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks. I have a copy of that book but my first looks into it were to find (almost) exactly this integral in this form. I don't understand actually your substitution. Could you please explain it a little bit for me?

Comment: @CameronWilliams In my "Inbox" folder I see part of a solution that you tried to give but when I open the question I cannot see it. Did you delete it?

Comment: I did delete it. I misread your integral and wrote stuff that wasn't relevant. I just suggested the hyperbolic substitution because it will make the Bessel function terms simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this integral does not converge, for example when $a=b=c=1$ as shown in http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E%28-x%5E2%29%28J_1%28%28x%5E2%2B1%29%5E%281%2F2%29%29%29%5E2%2Fx%2Cx%2C0%2Cinf and for example when $a=b=1$ and $c=0$ as shown in http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%28J_1%28%28x%5E2%2B1%29%5E%281%2F2%29%29%29%5E2%2Fx%2Cx%2C0%2Cinf.

Comment: +1 Actually, it's obvious (when you know you have to look for it, but I was lazy at first) since, if $J_1(a), J_1(b)$ are not null, there is a problem at $x=0$.